# CSS/HTML Can't figure out how to get an image to appear on site

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add an image as a sign in button to my website's header. When a user clicks/taps the button, it redirects them to the sign in page. I'm creating a ruby on rails app, and my image is located in "app/assets/images", but I can't seem to get my image to appear.

And I do not want to upload the image to a site such as imgur and link it to my site.

Here is what I've tried so far.

Attempting to link with CSS:

1) `background-image: url(../images/sign-in.png) no-repeat;`

2) `background: url(sigin-in.png);`

And I've tried getting it to work with `display: block; width:128px; height:128px; position: relative;`

Attempting to link with HTML:

```
<a type="button" class="navbar-toggle btn-signin">
    <img class="signin-img" scr="../images/sign-in.png">
</a>
```

Note: I've tried other methods in HTML too, such as creating `<button>` tags,`<div>` tags and`<a>` tags.

It's a ".png" image, does that play a factor for not appearing?

Comment: You told us your image is located in `app/assets/images`. Where is the current html file you are working on located?

Comment: Html file is located in: app/views/welcome/index.html.erb

Comment: Try using full path to image file, or creating a `data URI` of the image

Comment: I just tried using full path and it didn't work. And how do I create data URI? I don't know what that is

Comment: Have you tried `<img class="signin-img" scr="/app/assets/images/sign-in.png">`? According to https://www.sitepoint.com/a-quick-study-of-the-rails-directory-structure/, "app/assets/images
All the images required for the application should go into this directory. The images here are available in views through nifty helpers like image_tag("img_name.png") so that you don’t have to specify the relative or absolute path for images."

Comment: I just tried "<img class="signin-img" scr="/app/assets/images/sign-in.png">" and it didn't work. I have been reviewing my code, trying to check for an error. But everything looks ok. I encountered this problem many times unless I link the image from an online source, such as imgur.

Comment: Do you have a live page we can see?

Comment: No, it's only on local host.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `src` value of your image to `../../assets/images/sign-in.png`.

Your full image element should look like this:

`<img class="signin-img" src="../../assets/images/sign-in.png">`

Comment: how about `../../assets/images`?

Comment: Still didn't work. I have been messing with my css and html, trying to figure out a way to get it to work.

Comment: I think I figured it out. It should be `<img src='../../assets/images/sign-in.png'>`

Comment: If that didn't work, then your problem isn't your file structure, or you didn't double check your paths.

Comment: That's what im thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are mixing backgound-image and background-repeat:

```
background-image: url(../images/sign-in.png) no-repeat;
```

this should be:

```
background: url(../images/sign-in.png) no-repeat;
```

Also, in some RoR apps, using MVC pattern, the assets are being referenced from the root level of the app, so you might have to change the paths to the files.

probably you could try removing the "../"?

do you have any other images that are being correctly displayed?

good luck!

Comment: Still didn't work. This has happened to me before when creating RoR apps. And has only happened to me when making rails apps. I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue! I figured it had something to do with rails, since this only happens when I make rails apps/sites.

Since my html file is erb (embedded ruby), I had to "embed" the image in my html like this:

```
<img src="<%= asset_path( 'sign-in.png' ) %>" />
```

Thank you to everyone who answered!

Comment: Interesting. Glad you solved your problem and thanks for sharing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure it's `src` not `scr`.

```
<img class="signin-img" scr="../images/sign-in.png"> # bad
<img class="signin-img" src="../images/sign-in.png"> # good
```

Second, open up developer tools (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) and see if the browser is requesting the image:

```
images/sign-in.png
```

It will look like this: (make sure you're in the *network* tab)

[image]